# UITabBarController hides but white space remaining

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have UITabBarController in my app.
In a particular view I want to hide the tabbar and display the content up to the below line.

For that I used the code in the view

```
-(void)viewWillappear{

   [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "upto below line"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your content is, but if it's inside a container, like a UIView, you can change the autoResizingMask to be

`myView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

and it should do the right thing.